# c++ seekg seems to be returning a hex address instead of the actual char from .txt file

Tags: c++, file

I got a simple code snipped and I'm trying to learn how to read plain text using c++ libraries. In the same directory as the program I got `text1.txt` which contains lines of ASCII plain text. After I run the code I was expecting to obtain the same characters from `text1.txt` at `textOut.txt` Instead, at textOut.txt I have 100 lines of

> 0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018
>   0x7ffdf21fd018

here is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

fstream  afile;
afile.open("text1.txt", ios::in );   
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("textOut.txt");
int counter=0;
for( counter=0;counter<100;counter++ ){
   outfile << afile.seekg(counter);
   outfile << "\n";
   //printf("%d\n", counter);
   }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`seekg` returns `*this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg), so it is surprising that the `<<` operator works in this case at all.

Rather use

```
outfile << static_cast<char>(afile.get());
```

Full program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    fstream  afile;
    afile.open("text1.txt",ios::in);
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("textOut.txt");
    int counter=0;
    for (counter=0; counter<100; counter++) {

        afile.seekg(counter);
        outfile << static_cast<char>(afile.get());
        //outfile << afile.seekg(counter);
        outfile << "\n";
        //printf("%d\n", counter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```